# Directive doesn't fire after changing textarea model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a text with newline separator and URLs:

`first row\nFind me at http://www.example.com and also\n at http://stackoverflow.com`.

I want to update `ng-repeat` values after pressing on `copy` button.

I have this HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="myCntrl">
    <textarea ng-model="copy_note_value"></textarea>

    <button data-ng-click="copy()">copy</button>

    <div>
        <p ng-repeat="row in note_value.split('\n') track by $index"
           wm-urlify="row"
           style="display: inline-block;"
            >
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('myCntrl', function ($scope) {

     $scope.note_value = "first row\nFind me at http://www.example.com and also\n at http://stackoverflow.com";

     $scope.copy_note_value = angular.copy($scope.note_value);

    $scope.copy = function(){
      $scope.note_value = angular.copy($scope.copy_note_value);   
    }

});
```

I have directive that should take text and return *urlfied* text:

```
app.directive('wmUrlify', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            function urlify(text) {
                var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
                return text.replace(urlRegex, function (url) {
                    return '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank">' + url + '</a>';
                })
            }

            var text = $parse(attrs.wmUrlify)(scope);
            var html = urlify(text);
            element[0].inneHtml(html)

        }
    };
}]);
```

Here is a flow:  User changes text in `textarea` and presses on `copy` button. I expect to show the change in `ng-repeat`.

It works only if I add a new line and not line content.

What is wrong here? This is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljq7j8er/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `track by $index` from your `ng-repeat`. This is because you are telling Angular that the value of `note_value.split('\n')` will only be changed when there is a change in the `$index` i.e. size of the array after splitting by new line.

But the default implementation of `track by` is the identity of each item. So when you changed the default implementation to track it by the `$index` and when you are not not adding a new line instead just updating the content of any existing line, Angular is not able to detect that there is a change.

**Update**

Removing the `track by $index` function will throw an exception when there are same values after split. So you can use a simple function like: (define it in your controller)

```
$scope.indexFunction = function($index, val) {
    // Creating an unique identity based on the index and the value
    return $index + val;
};
```

And then use it in your `ng-repeat` like:

```
<p ng-repeat="row in note_value.split('\n') track by indexFunction($index, row)"></p>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: but what happens if u have duplicate values after split? This use case should lead to exception `Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]`

Comment: Well, I knew it :-) I left that for you to figure out. I've updated the answer. Please check it out.