# AngularJS Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]

Tags: php, angularjs, json

I am getting JSON data with PHP but on ng-repeat getting error:

`[ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in repeater are not allowed`

I tried to `track by $index` but every time browser crashing with `track by $index`, working perfectly in `localhost` but on Web Hosting getting the above error.

Any Solution?

JSON data:

```
{
  id : "1",
  title : "Title1",
  src : "Source1"
},
{
  id : "2",
  title : "Title2",
  src : "Source2"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this. Define a method in your controller scope:

```
$scope.getIndexFunction = function($index, data) {
    // Generate a unique string so that ng-repeat can avoid error
    return $index + '' + data.toString();
};
```

Now, in your view:

```
<div ng-repeat="source in sources track by getIndexFunction($index, source)"> {{source.title}}</div>
```

[Directive doesn't fire after changing textarea model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34265554/directive-doesnt-fire-after-changing-textarea-model/34265727#34265727)